# CSS display: unset not functioning in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table which I need to dynamically remove the table styling from.  Position: absolute (which is what I need) works in a table, but only in Firefox.

Because I am dynamically modifying the width of the columns, I'm using a colgroup to store the initial width of the columns - I retrieve the width from there when loading the page.  In Chrome, setting the width property on a div with display: colgroup does not seem to work (unsurprising).  I don't think that I can avoid doing this, as I don't know the data or format of the table in advance.

When I'm removing the table styling, I can generally just overwrite the display property.  However, if I overwrite the display property on a div with display: col, Chrome fails to recognize that it can have width.  This is true whether I use javascript to set display: unset or css to do so.  If I uncheck the display property in the inspector or use the inspector to apply display: unset, it works the way that I would expect - width can then be set and read.

I'm sure I can hack around this issue (although it would be nice if I don't have to), but I want to understand why it's breaking - is it just a Chrome bug?

Comment: Add a code snippet so we can help you better.

Comment: Post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The unset value is sort of a combination of initial and inherit.

When unset is applied to a property, it will apply either initial or inherit, depending on what the property's default behaviour is.

See docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

Also, `display: colgroup` and `display: col` do not exist, it should be:

`display: table-column-group` and `display: table-column`

See CSS display docs https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp